# Left justified comments for ESS

Tags: emacs, comments, ess

When I use `C-M-\` (with emacs and ESS) to format my R code, it right justifies my comments. For example, it changes:

```
#This is a comment
x=5
```

to

```
                       #This is a comment
x=5
```

How do I stop my comments being right-justified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to use `##`. By convention, that one doesn't move.